# Matrix Algebra (Elementary)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have $\hat\xi =\lambda_1\textbf{1V}^{-1} + \lambda_2\textbf{rV}^{-1}$ and sub it in to my two constraints, namely, $\xi\textbf{1}^T = 1$ and $\xi\textbf{r}^T = \mu$. My lecture notes then say set $\textbf{r}\textbf{V}^{-\textbf{1}}\textbf{1}^T$ = $\textbf{1} \textbf{V}^{-1}\textbf{r}^T = \beta$.

$\textbf{V}$ is a diagonal matrix here.

Why is this okay?

Comment: It would help to define the terms in your question.  What are $\mathbf{r}$, $\mathbf{V}$ and $\mathbf{1}$?

Comment: The context is deriving Markowitz mean-variance efficient frontier do you think it would be useful to include this?

Comment: I just meant that you should define what type of mathematical objects these things are.  Is $\mathbf{V}$ a square matrix with real entries?  Is $\mathbf{r}$ a vector?  Is $\mathbf{1}$ the identity matrix?  Without these definitions, it's hard to know exactly what you're asking?

Comment: To add to Alistair's point, typically $\mathbf{1}$ denotes the column (not row) vector of all ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbf{V}$ is diagonal (hence symmetric), you have $(\mathbf{r} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{1}^T)^T = \mathbf{1} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{r}^T$ (using the fact that $(AB)^T = B^T A^T$ for matrices $A$ and $B$).

I'm guessing from what you've written that $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{1}$ are vectors of sizes such that $\mathbf{r} \mathbf{V}^{-1} \mathbf{1}^T$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix (i.e. a scalar).  The lecture notes call this scalar $\beta$.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a scalar, $y^T Ax = (y^T Ax)^T = x^TA^Ty $ which is equal to $x^TAy$ when $A$ is symmetric.